# vba code for copy from one powerpoint to paste in another powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have PPT1 where I need to copy from PPT2 which has 4 slide which will go to always in end in PPT1.

Could anyone help me to write code in PPT as I have not idea to give range in PPts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can directly copy paste then drag down or up for sequence .

Comment: I could but its bug slide and its weekly activity

Comment: not getting you

Comment: I mean, I have 3 ppt like this with 30-35 slide in each and this is weekly activity.  To drag and down every week I thought to write code for it. As I wanted to paste PPT2 at the end of my main (PPT1)